# How to reduce an array to object while providing auto code completion in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Lately I'm trying out typescript and while diving into it I was stuck at one place where I wasn't able move forward. So I have an array of strings and I want to reduce it into an object while getting all proper hinting and code completion. Although I've arrived to a place where typescript isn't throwing any error but still I wasn't able to achieve the code completion behaviour. Pasting out the sample code here for reference.

```
interface GetObjI {
  [key: string]: string;
}

function getObj(myArray: string[]): GetObjI {
  return myArray.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    prev[curr] = curr;
    return prev;
  }, {});
}

const arr = ["name", "age"];

const obj = getObj(arr);

console.log(obj.age); // Here I wasn't able to achieve code completion.
```

Comment: I have a similar problem in a home-grown Redux alternative, converting a hash of pure functions into a hash of pre-bound functions. TS understands the bare functions but has no understanding of the bound collection. Very interested to see what the community has for this.

Comment: @Tom I think for a hash keyof can sort it out?

Answer (score 1):

With strict TypeScript settings, the code you have *should* be throwing an error.

```
prev[curr] = curr;
```

throws

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
>
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.(7053)

Which makes sense - you aren't providing any special type for the accumulator when you're passing it in, so assigning to a property of it doesn't mesh with its existing type (as an empty object).

Use a generic type argument to indicate the type of the accumulator, and make `getObj` generic too so that the values in `myArray` can be passed along (rather than using just `string[]`, which is too general).

You also need to type the array passed in `as const` so it doesn't get widened to `string[]` before the function call.

```
function getObj<T extends readonly string[]>(myArray: T) {
    // Type out the type of the full object with all properties here to be DRY
    type Accum = Record<T[number], T[number]>;
    // The object doesn't have all properties inside the callback, though
    // so we need to use Partial to indicate that some or all can be missing
    return myArray.reduce<Partial<Accum>>((prev, curr: T[number]) => {
        prev[curr] = curr;
        return prev;
    }, {}) as Accum; // When returning, indicate that it's no longer Partial, but has all properties
}

const arr = ["name", "age"] as const;

const obj = getObj(arr);

console.log(obj.age);
```

But `.reduce` is [not the right tool for this situation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg) - it requires verbose TypeScript typing and is not a great idea even in standard JavaScript because the accumulator remains the same object. Just use a loop.

```
function getObj<T extends readonly string[]>(myArray: T) {
    const obj: Record<string, string> = {};
    for (const prop of myArray) {
        obj[prop] = prop;
    }
    return obj as Record<T[number], T[number]>;
}
```

Or use `Object.fromEntries`

```
const getObj = <T extends readonly string[]>(myArray: T) =>
    Object.fromEntries(myArray.map(prop => [prop, prop])) as Record<T[number], T[number]>;
```

Unfortunately, all of these approaches do require helping TS along with some type assertions. Using a loop or `reduce` requires the properties to be typed as optional inside the loop, but required outside of it - and `Object.fromEntries` only gives a type of `Record<string, T>` in response, which isn't quite specific enough.

Comment: Could you add some comments or something to explain the intricacies of the typing on getObj and of the `Accum` type? And why is the type info for `reduce` provided as `reduce<stuff>` instead of declaring types on the iterator args and/or the initial value? These are all things that should be explained.

Comment: The type paramter passed to `.reduce` is the type for the accumulator. It basically does the same thing as asserting the type when passing the second parameter, eg `}, {} as SomeType);`

Comment: I appreciate the explanation  but any of the above mentioned methods ain't do auto completion, I wonder how Record<T[number],T[number]> makes much sense but still TS isn't able to pull off the purpose.

Comment: @classydraught Autocompletion works fine for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWA4C.png Any of the snippets *should* let TS properly infer that the call of `getObj` returns something of type `Record<T[number], T[number]>`. If you want a live demo too, see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygeQEYCsYF4YB4AqMCAHlAmACYQzQBOAlmHANoC6AfABQC2AngIK1aAQ14AuGPgCU2dgCgYimGnQJgUAHQAzWiG4BRMFAYIIPAUNEbuwgA6dbu27JjNHIWwBoY726ykywtQASmogtBQEzGAArtyoCLSs3vjRcQlJ7ADccnKgkLDCQtiuAERgwtwIpd6lwoilrDl54NAwIBgliCgYnEW0Us35ECAANggaoyBwnB3oGvUIg0A

Comment: @CertainPerformance That's not autocompletion, Its just a feature provided by vscode that will popup all the matching strings in the file. https://ibb.co/cwLHN5s

Comment: @classydraught Oh, I see what you mean, you need `as const` too. (Wish there way to apply `as const` on everything by default, default widening and assumed mutability messes a lot of things up)

Comment: @CertainPerformance exactly!!, I was thinking of a solution where `as const` can be used so that the return object can't be widened proper code completion can be achieved.

Comment: @classydraught Yes, you need to use `as const`, and the type will be properly inferred then, including TS detection and autocompletion of an object with the properties of the array you pass in.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think using `as const` ahead defeats the whole developer experience as I believe no developer want's to do that every time he uses `getObj` function.

Comment: @classydraught Without `as const` (or something even more verbose), there's no way to do what you want - it's completely impossible to go from a type of `string[]` to `'age' | 'name'` unless you start with a type structure that includes both properties to begin with. If you're just given `string[]`, there just isn't enough information to extract out of that, no matter the implementation of the function.